# Should I use Android tab layout for long lists?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have to display long lists of job names for each letter of the alphabet.  Each list will come from a database.  Is a tab layout appropriate?

Comment: what do you mean by long? 10, 100, or 10000 or even more items? It depends...

Comment: I'd take RecyclerView

Comment: Each list might have around 700 entries

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Patrick!  I am going to use a viewpagerindicator to swipe across the alphabet, and use recyclerview to show the long lists.

Answer (score -1):

you can use scrollspy technique in the bootstrap [scroll spy technique](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-examples)

just put all your alphabets in the nav tab bar then fill all your data in single page and divided it accordingly to your alphabets. 
put the target area (**i.e div ID**) to your each alphabets to their respective area.This will allow the user to scroll through single page and

> user don't have to load multiple pages.

This will improve the user convenience.

Comment: The user's question belongs to Android not Bootstrap.

Comment: oh sry.. i thought he was asking about mobile site